# Using css DIV areas in View Script

Tags: html, css, zend-framework2, zend-form

In my layout script I have some css areas, like:

```
<div id="section-navigation">
            Test
</div>
```

How can I override these sections in my view script with other data? I´d like to override it dynamically.

here is a snippet of my layout.phtml

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/grid.css'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><img src="./Images/cheyenne.jpg" alt="cheyenne-IT consulting" width="490" height="115" /><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'arbeitskalender', 'action'=>'index'));?>">Arbeitskalender</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="section-navigation">
            test
        </div>

        <div id="aside">
            test
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?= $this->layout()->content ?>
        </div>

  </div>
  <div id="footer">
            copyright 2014  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Probably there is another property in the form layout?

```
$this->layout()->content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the links you would have in the navigation `<div>` changes for every action and you want to set it dinamically, then you could create a custom view script file and render it in your layout.

Something like this :

**navigation.phtml:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->link; ?>"><?php echo $this->name; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then add it to the `view_manager` in your `module.config`:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
         //.....
        'navigation/view' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/navigation.phtml',
    ),
```

In your **action (controller) :**

```
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('route-name',
                                array('controller'=>'arbeitskalender', 
                                      'action'=>'index')
                              );
$navlinks = new ViewModel(
                array(
                   'link'    => $url ,
                   'name'    => 'Arbeitskalender'
                )
);
$navlinks ->setTemplate('navigation/view');
$nav= $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface')
                                ->render($navlinks);

$viewLayout = new ViewModel(array('nav' => $nav));
return $viewLayout;
```

In your **layout :**

```
<div id="section-navigation">
   <?php echo $this->nav; ?> 
</div>
```

You could also see the [Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html#zend-view-helpers-initial-partial). Create a partial script like this:

```
<?php // partial.phtml ?>
<ul>
 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->link; ?>"><?php echo $this->name; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

And then call it from your layout script using the following:

```
<div id="section-navigation">
 <?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'link' => $this->link,
    'name' => $this->name)); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the second one, and it works quite fine. The first solution might be better but at the moment I´m not that deep in the ZEND theme. thanks